# Change entries URL?

Tags: entry, url, titles

In ExpressionEngine was a URL field under the title field that was filled when writing the title.

It was possible to change the URL to something else.
Also if i want to change the title of an entry and also want the URL to be the same, how do i do that?

Do i really need to delete the entry and make the same entry again with another title?

Is there maybe a plugin for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the Slug at the top of the right sidebar when editing an entry.

Comment: Damn i didn't see that. I was searching google for n hour and a plugin and it's there. Is there a way to move that under the title field that you have it in view?

Comment: I don't know of a way to move it. I expect it could be changed by a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you would like to make sure that the slug is always the same as the title.
If so, then this plugin will work.

https://github.com/internetztube/craft-slug-equals-title

Comment: But you can't change the URL to something else?

Comment: What do you mean with “something else”?

Comment: Another URL than the title.

Comment: That is now supported. @MrGlasspoole